# Convert geometry_ msgs/Pose to Point

Tags: ros, pose, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all!,

i got a Pose`std::vector<geometry_msgs::Pose> waypoints` and now i would like to transform it to geometry_msgs::Point.
I tried to convert it to Eigen and afterwards in Point. My first step would be something like:

```
std::vector<geometry_msgs::Pose> m;
m = waypoints;
Eigen::Affine3d e;
tf::poseMsgToEigen(m,e);
```

and i get an error: no matching function for call to poseMsgToEigen.
Do you have any suggestions ?

Greetings
mutu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249104/convert-geometry_-msgs/pose-to-point/) by [mutu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28552/mutu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-11-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Mutu,

A `geometry_msgs::Pose` actually contains a `geometry_msgs::Point` as you can read in the [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html).

to get the pose just type:

```
geometry_msgs::Point pt = waypoints[i].position;
```

for the index `i` that you want. Do note that you lose the orientation information that is also contained in the pose.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mutu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28552/mutu/) on 2016-12-01**:
thank you! That solved my problem!